# how I can divide a sum number into 50 column in ecxel?

Tags: excel, random, divide

I would like to tell, with a smaller number of columns.
Let's say we have a sum of 24 and we want to distribute it randomly into 10 separate columns. we should get such a result as below I wrote.

[image: desired result]

Is there a formula in Excel like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a search on here, similar questions have been asked fairly recently...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is what I would do...

For each required split, select a random number between zero and the remainder of the distribution qty, multiplied by the percentage of how many splits have already been calculated. This prevents the first few splits being very high, and the rest being zero.

I would also add a check for the very last split to make sure that it equals whatever is left of the original distribution qty.

Here is an image for illustration and the formula that I have used:

[image]

```
=IF($A2=MAX($A:$A),$F$1-SUM($B$1:$B1),RANDBETWEEN(0,($F$1-SUM($B$1:$B1))*($A2/MAX($A:$A))))
```

Hopefully, this isn't too complex to understand. If you need further explanation, please let me know.

You can simply change the distribution qty in the yellow box, and if you want more splits, all you need to do is drag down columns A & B to the required number.